# what is the best way to have one image overlap another on an html page for all browsers

Tags: jquery, html, css, image, z-index

i have two spans:

```
<span id="top" ><img src="top.png" /></span>
<span id="bottom" ><img src="bottom.png" /></span>
```

how can i have it where:

1. The top image overlaps over the bottom image
2. Make sure the top images shows up in front of the bottom image) (instead of behind it)
3. make sure that alignment is consistent across browsers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@ooo; you can give `position:relative` to your span because `z-index` works only on `position absolute & relative` right like this:

css:

```
span{position:relative;display:block}
#top{z-index:1;}
#bottom{margin-top:-20px}
```

html:

```
<span id="top" ><img src="top.png" /></span>
<span id="bottom" ><img src="bottom.png" /></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
span { position:relative;display:block; }
#bottom { z-index: 1;margin-top:-10px; }
#top { z-index: 2; }
```

That should overlap them a bit.  The CSS really depends on how much they are supposed to overlap...

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the elements in a container;

```
<div id="image-container">
    <span id="top" ><img src="top.png" /></span>
    <span id="bottom" ><img src="bottom.png" /></span>
</div>
```

Set the css of the container to `position: relative;`

Then use;

```
#top {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
}
#bottom{
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

Using `left` and `top` to position your images.

This should give the most consistent result across browsers. It should be especially favoured over the use of margins to position the images due to the potential of elements being susceptible to the double margin bug present in earlier versions of IE.